# Android TabPagerAdapter: not working properly on older APIs

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I'm having a problem with a FragmentPagerAdapter.

I've successfully used it in other parts of my app, but now I've run into this nasty issue: on older APIs, when I swipe from one tab to the other one, everything is working flawlessly, but when I change the tab by clicking on the title, it gets selected, but the underlying fragment is not changing.

I've started to think that the problem may be caused by the fact that this pager is nested inside another fragment. Still, it's so strange that I'm able to change the tab by swiping it, but not by clicking on the title.

Here's my code:

```
public class PetrolStationFragment extends Fragment {

private PetrolStation mPetrolStation;

private int mPetrolStationIndex;

private AppCompatImageView mLogo;
private TextView mNameTextView;
private CheckBox mCheckBox;
private TextView mAddressTextView;
private TextView mDistanceTextView;
private Switch mSwitch;
private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

private static TabLayout mTabLayout;
private static ViewPager mViewPager;
private static int intItems = 2;


// Design pattern to instantiate a new fragment.
public static PetrolStationFragment newInstance(int petrolStationIndex) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PETROL_STATION_INDEX, petrolStationIndex);

    PetrolStationFragment fragment = new PetrolStationFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}

/********************************************************/

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mPetrolStationIndex = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PETROL_STATION_INDEX);
    mPetrolStation = PetrolStationsArray.get().getItem(mPetrolStationIndex);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceStace) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_petrol_station, container, false);

    mLogo = (AppCompatImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ps_logo);
    mNameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.petrol_station);
    mCheckBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    mAddressTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.address);
    mDistanceTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.distance);
    mSwitch = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.on_service);

    mLogo.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), getPetrolStationLogo(mPetrolStation.getLogo())));
    mNameTextView.setText(mPetrolStation.getName());
    mCheckBox.setChecked(mPetrolStation.isFavourite());
    mAddressTextView.setText(mPetrolStation.getAddress());

    // To start the marquee-effect on the address TextView.
    mAddressTextView.setSelected(true);

    LatLng centre = getLocation();
    LatLng point = new LatLng(mPetrolStation.getLat(), mPetrolStation.getLon());

    if (centre == null) {
        mDistanceTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.distence_nd));
    } else {
        double distance = computeDistance(centre, point);
        mDistanceTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.distance_km, distance));
    }

    // TODO: to fix.
    mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isFavourite) {
            // mPetrolStation.setFavourite(isFavourite);
        }
    });

    ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mGoogleMap = googleMap;
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);

            double lat = mPetrolStation.getLat();
            double lon = mPetrolStation.getLon();
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lon);

            mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));

            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15);
            mGoogleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
        }
    });

    // Setup Views.
    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.pager_header);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    // Set an Adapter for the View Pager.
    TabPagerAdapter tabPagerAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(tabPagerAdapter);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(SELF_SERVICE_TAB_POSITION);

    mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}

class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    // Return fragment with respect to position.
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment;

        switch (position) {

            case SELF_SERVICE_TAB_POSITION: {
                fragment = SelfServiceFragment.newInstance(mPetrolStationIndex);

                return fragment;
            }

            case FULL_SERVICE_TAB_POSITION: {
                fragment = FullServiceFragment.newInstance(mPetrolStationIndex);

                return fragment;
            }

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return intItems;
    }

    // This method returns the title of the tab according to its position.
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {

            case SELF_SERVICE_TAB_POSITION: {
                String mSelfService = getResources().getString(R.string.self_service);

                return mSelfService;
            }

            case FULL_SERVICE_TAB_POSITION: {
                String mFullService = getResources().getString(R.string.full_service);

                return mFullService;
            }

        }

        return null;
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pretty obvious: I was using a `static TabLayout`
and a `static ViewPager`: it was a mistake, 'cause my TabPager is inside of another ViewPager.

Answer (score 0):

in a fragment you are creating new fragments i guess. I've used fragments in a similar kind of scenario and I created new fragment instances in the tabadapter.the code looks something like this:

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

```
public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return new MeFragment();
        case 1:
            return new CommunityFragment();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

}

I'm adding this mainactivity have look at it, maybe it'll help:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
public static Activity activity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    activity = this;
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new MeFragment(),"Me");
    adapter.addFragment(new CommunityFragment(),"Community");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager){
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle (int position){
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you look at my code, that's the same thing I've done.

Comment: Try using a adapter for your viewpager, I added the tabs through that adapter and it worked fine.